# on DELETE MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 251:

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

Hello i try to delete my comments in Laravel 5.4, but unfortunately i get this error. Can't really get where is the problem.

This is my form:

```
<form action="{{route('comments.destroy', $comment->id) }}">
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">DELETE</button>
    </div>
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
</form>
```

This is my routes:

```
// Comments
Route::post('/lots/{lot}/comments', 'CommentsController@store');
Route::get('/comments', 'CommentsController@show');
Route::get('comments/{id}/edit', ['uses' => 'CommentsController@edit', 'as' => 'comments.edit']);
Route::put('comments/{id}', ['uses' => 'CommentsController@update', 'as' => 'comments.update']);
Route::delete('comments/{id}', ['uses' => 'CommentsController@destroy', 'as' => 'comments.destroy']);
Route::get('comments/{id}/delete', ['uses' => 'CommentsController@delete', 'as' => 'comments.delete']);
```

This is the controller:

```
public function delete($id)
    {
        $comment = Comment::find($id);
        return view('comments.delete')->withComment($comment);
    }

public function destroy($id)
    {
        $comment = Comment::find($id);
        $comment->delete();

        return back();
    }
```

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

This is the error message: 
[image]

Comment: what was the solution?

Comment: @ShanikaEdiriweera the Parth Vora answer is  the solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
<form action="{{ route('comments.destroy', ['id' => $comment->id]) }}" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">DELETE</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: How it will look for PUT method ? i try to change route to 'comments.update' and changed {{ method_field('PUT') }} but it didnt work, just redirect me back to the edit page

Comment: If it redirected back without any errors that mean your form validation get failed.

Comment: Thanks! i just need to set up flash messages

Comment: How did this get fixed? I am getting the same error. I am attaching the action dynamically since my delete modal is a popup. `$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#deleteNoticeModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
            var id = button.data('id')
            var action = "{{ route('removeNotice', "id")}}"
            var url = action.replace("id", id)
            $('#userForm').attr("action", url);
        });
    });`

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the problem, Its your form action's route syntax which is wrong. [route helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-route)

```
<form action="{{route('comments.destroy', ['id' => $comment->id]) }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">DELETE</button>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
</form>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help .  How i understand, csrf_token needed only when you have PUT and POST requests

Comment: it still didn't work the error message is same and this is the link ` http://127.0.0.1:8000/comments/3?_token=JUsTMFEwh5hyunnTZtPYYRHSurlihre9wxSOcejY&_method=DELETE `

Comment: that localhost link only works on your computer, bdw  `return redirect()->route('comments.browse')` Do you have a route named `comments.browse` ?

Comment: @DmitryMalys I think the problem was with your action route, the way you passed the ID, check my answer again now I've edited it

Comment: unfortunately dint helped ... the error is same. this is link was generated comments/2?_token=JUsTMFEwh5hyunnTZtPYYRHSurlihre9wxSOcejY&_method=DELETE

Comment: @DmitryMalys strange, let us continue this discussion on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144038/sapnesh-naik

Comment: i dont have enough reputation on stack to talk in chat :(

Comment: @DmitryMalys just a hunch try putting delete input field in the begining of the form

Comment: didt help, maybe i should use form helpers?

Comment: Just inspect the form tag and show me what action it has.

Answer (score 0):

In my case my error was that I was not setting the id property on the object sent to the view, and that was why the form action URL didn't have it.

Check that you are setting **id** property in your **comment** object, so the URL is parsed as: **.../comments/####**

e.g.

`$photos = Photo::all()->select('id', 'name')->get();
return view('photos.index')->with('photos', $photos);`